How to get pyautogui working on Fedora 40
I am trying to use pyautogui in Pycharm. I imported pyautogui and now get the error
NOTE: You must install tkinter on Linux to use MouseInfo. Run the following: sudo apt-get install python3-tk python3-dev
So I installed python3-tkinter and python3-devel with sudo dnf install x respectively.
The error code still persists. I have looked on other sites but found no information which I could use.
If there is other information you may need please let me know!
Also: As this is my first post here. If there is anything I could or should improve please tell me so!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
